I want to optimise/remove things from my variable importance Plot
I'm currently trying to visualise my variable importance plot but my plot looks all squished. I'm not very familiar with R so I wanted to ask if anyone know how to make the Plots more readable/better looking or how I can remove the MeanDecreaseGini part completely?
model <- randomForest(Y ~ ., data = data, ntree = 500, importance = TRUE, proximity = TRUE)

varImpPlot(model, n.var = 15)

I tried using
randomForest::varImpPlot(model, 
                        sort=FALSE, 
                        main="Variable Importance Plot")

but it didn't help.
Plot

Using a toy example, one option could be to save the varImpPlot output (first plot) as a data frame, then use ggplot2 which has a high degree of customisation flexibility (second plot). Or plot more selectively (third plot).
library(randomForest)
library(tidyverse)
library(janitor)

set.seed(4543)
data(mtcars)
rf <- randomForest(mpg ~ .,
  data = mtcars, ntree = 1000,
  importance = TRUE,
  proximity = TRUE
)

vi <- varImpPlot(rf)



vi2 <- vi |>
  as_tibble(rownames = "variable") |>
  clean_names() |>
  pivot_longer(-variable)

# Equivalent plot
vi2 |>
  mutate(variable = fct_reorder(variable, value)) |>
  ggplot(aes(value, variable)) +
  geom_col() +
  facet_wrap(~name, scales = "free_x") +
  theme_bw() +
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL)



# Selective plot
vi2 |>
  filter(name == "percent_inc_mse") |>
  mutate(variable = fct_reorder(variable, value)) |>
  ggplot(aes(value, variable)) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_label(aes(label = round(value, 1))) +
  theme_bw() +
  labs(title = "% Increase in MSE", x = NULL, y = NULL)


Created on 2024-04-14 with reprex v2.1.0
